# using a string to access deep array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a return result which is in JSON format.  I use JSON.parse on this to convert it to an array (mydata).  I then have a string such as "/a/b/c" which would map to mydata["a"]["b"]["c"].  I would like to be able to change the value pointed at by "/a/b/c".  My issue is how do I access this so the final value pointed to can be modified?

I was thinking along the lines of

```
var mydata = JSON.parse( json_string );
var newValue = 2;
var path="a/b/c";
var s = path.split("/");
var ptr = mydata;
for( int ii=0; ii < s.length; ii++ ) {
    ptr = ptr[ s[ii] ];
}
ptr = newValue;
```

But this does not work for obvious reasons.  What could I do to make this work?

Comment: Assigning a new value to a variable **never** changes the value of another variable or property (unless you are using `with` or are in global scope, but lets not go there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to stop iterating one pass earlier.  If you dereference all of the way down to `a.b.c` you'll likely have a value field, not an object field.

Since you're copying the value field, overwriting `ptr` has no effect of the original.

However if you stop at `ptr = mydata['a']['b']` you can then modify `ptr['c']`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop one step before the end:

```
var mydata = JSON.parse( json_string );
var newValue = 2;
var path="a/b/c";
var s = path.split("/");
var ptr = mydata;
for (var ii=0; ii < s.length - 1; ii++) {
    ptr = ptr[s[ii]];
}
ptr[s[s.length-1]] = newValue;
```